# show the values that exist in sublist that does not exist in another sublists's list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Let's say I have this list, `webinars`, with sublists in it.

```
[['aword1','aword2','aword3'],['bword1','bword2','bword3'],['nword1','nword2','nword3'],['maz','da','cool']]
```

I have this other list, called the `healthinars`, with sublists in it.

```
[['aword1','aurl'],['kawa','burl'],['nword1','n url']]
```

My aim is the following:

If the first value of any sublists of `webinars` does not exist in `healthinars`, bring me the first and third value of any sublists of `webinars`.

In this example, it would be

- bword1,bword3
- maz,cool

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's the result you're getting with what you tried? Where are you struggling exactly with what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd first construct a set of healthinars names, then iterate over all webinars to check if their name is in the healthinars name set:

```py
webinars = [
    ["aword1", "aword2", "aword3"],
    ["bword1", "bword2", "bword3"],
    ["nword1", "nword2", "nword3"],
    ["maz", "da", "cool"],
]
healthinars = [["aword1", "aurl"], ["kawa", "burl"], ["nword1", "n url"]]

healthinars_names = {event[0] for event in healthinars}

for name, attr2, attr3 in webinars:
    if name not in healthinars_names:
        print(name, attr3)
```

It gives:

```
bword1 bword3
maz cool
```

as expected, hope I did understand correctly though...